# When to suppress parameter in function notation

Tags: functions, notation

For example, a differential equation of the form $$\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=f(x),$$ has the general solution
$$y=\mu^{-1}\int\mu f(x)\,dx +C\mu^{-1},$$ where $\mu$ is the integrating factor $\mu(x)=\exp{(\int P(x)\,dx)}$.

So the way I've written this, the parameter for the integrating factor is suppressed when I write it down in the solution but when I defined it, I explicitly say it is a function of $x$. However, for $f(x)$, I write the parameter explicitly in the solution because it felt wrong otherwise. Further, for $y,$ I also suppressed the parameter.

My question, then, is whether or not this is the best way to write it. Is there a general consensus on when to explicitly state the independent variable in the notation? And is it a problem that I'm somewhat inconsistent on when I did it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"whether or not this is the best way to write it"*

This depends on the audience for your (attempt) at mathematical communication. Attempts to communicate can be very successful, moderately successful, et al. It can be a heap of trouble if the audience thinks they've understood, but in fact have misunderstood.

Sometimes the audience is yourself, as in your personal notes. In my notes I write $\int f$ rather than $\int f(x) dx$ if there can be no misunderstanding among the audience members (me).

Your audience might be undergraduates, graduate students, your advisor, a roomful of people of very different backgrounds.

Opinions on "the best way to write it" will vary with the *feelings* of various people, to use your word.

A very general consensus is unlikely, I'd say, for the question of "when to explicitly state the independent variable".

Lastly you ask about consistency within your own presentation. I don't know if it is a major problem. I think you are following a common practice: to be more explicit when introducing a dependent quantity for the first time, but then announce that the dependence will be implicit later on. It is a trade-off. You are buying a sleeker presentation at the cost of possible misunderstanding later on, among certain members of the audience.